# IOS Impliment OneHand Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have searched on google but I can't find anything regarding this. I want to implement onehand keyboard for iPhone 6 and 6+ like this [One Hand Keyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/one-handed-keyboard/id922361972?mt=8) using iOS 8 **app extension**. I know how to implement customkeyboard for single use but want to know how to implement it for right and left side.

[image: Leftside keyboard]

[image: Rightside keyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a `UIView` on `self.view` and set all **keys (buttons)** on it instead of directly adding on `self.view` and add all layout constraints according to this view. By doing this you can increase/decrease the x-origin of keys container view.

[image]

So for example you can do something like this:

**Left Align**

```
CGRect rect = keysContainerView.frame;
rect.origin.x = 0.0;
keysContainerView.frame = rect;
```

**Right Align**

```
CGRect rect = keysContainerView.frame;
rect.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(keysContainerView.frame);
keysContainerView.frame = rect;
```